# 'Cannot find module fingerprintjs2' error when importing the library in Angular project

Tags: angular, fingerprintjs2

I am trying to use fingerprint2.js in Angular project.

First, I installed the library via:

```
npm install fingerprintjs2
```

Added:

`./node_modules/fingerprintjs2/fingerprint2.js` in `angular.json` file in scripts section.

Imported the library in app.module.ts or myservice.ts as:

```
import * as Fingerprint2 from 'fingerprintjs2'
```

After importing, I am getting `Cannot find module 'fingerprintjs2'` error.

Is there any solution? What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem with fingerprintjs2 after I upgraded to 2.0.4. Going back to version 2.0.3 fixed it. They changed something in the latest release around module.exports: https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2/commit/1e07962c04bb473af6c024e562b60f11581d6a99

Answer (score 0):

I have to import and use this lib this way:

```
 import Fingerprint2 from 'fingerprintjs2';
    constructor() {
    Fingerprint2.getV18((result: string) => {
            const fingerPrint = result;
        });
    }
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fingerprint-library-6dyhqp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts